# Select an html class to show and hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML code that I'm building dynamically based on a `$.get` JSON.

```
<div class="forum-post">
  <div>
    <span class="forum-title">Test post</span><span class="forum-type label label-forum-Discussion">Discussion</span>
  </div>

  <div class="forum-author">
    By: Jared De La Cruz on Thursday, June 27, 2013 7:17:43 PM
  </div>
  <pre>
    This is a test post
  </pre>

  <div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-mini btn-primary btn-forum-comment" id="51ccf2471238f1cc13000003"><i class="icon-comment icon-white"></i> comment</a>
  </div>

  <div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-mini btn-inverse btn-forum-comment-show" id="51ccf2471238f1cc13000003"><i class="icon-plus-sign icon-white"></i> show</a>
  </div>

  <div class="forum-comments">
    <div class="forum-author">
      By: Jared De La Cruz on Saturday, June 29, 2013 11:56:29 PM
    </div>
    <pre>
      This is a test comment
    </pre>
  </div>
  <hr style="border-top: 1px dotted #b0b0b0;border-bottom: 0px">
</div>
```

The list of comments can grow large. When the user clicks show I would like the forum comments to show/hide.

```
// Button dynamic comment show
$("#forum").delegate(".btn-forum-comment-show", "click", function() {
  var post = $(this).parents(".forum-comments");
  console.log(post);
});
```

How can I grab the selector `.forum-comments` of the selected post? Similarly as I would as `$('#ID').hide();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `parent`/`closest` + `next` methods:

```
$("#forum").delegate(".btn-forum-comment-show", "click", function() {
   $(this).parent().next(".forum-comments").toggle();
});
```

Comment: This works great. why must i call parent? and next? Also if i add style to the class .forum-comments to style="visibility: hidden;" would it work?

Comment: @Jareddlc `parent` selects the parent element of the selected element and `next` selects the very next sibling element, `toggle` works with `display` property,  if you want to modify the visibility, you can add and remove classes using `toggleClass` method, or use `css` method which I don't recommend. Note that if you are using jQuery 1.7.2+ you can use `on` method instead if `delegate`.

Comment: well i would like to initialize my comments as hidden first, because right now there are getting in initialized displayed. Thanks!